# query database onClick in Remix.run

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

I am experimenting with `Remix.run` I am familiar with the SSR use of the `loader()` function. Does remix offer a way to query a database and manage state from within the component?

I am trying to fetch some data `onClick`

```
{next && <button onClick={handleFetchMore}>NEXT</button>}
```

```
  const handleFetchMore = async () => {
    try {
      const nextSet = await fetchCharacters(7);

      console.log("res", nextSet);
    } catch (err: any) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
  };
```

this function is not returning any data and triggers an error, however from within the `loader()` function `fetchCharacters()` return the correct data

Answer (score 0):

You can use a fetcher to call your loader, and get the next batch of results.

There's an infinite scroll example in the remix repository which seems to be doing what you want: https://github.com/remix-run/examples/blob/main/infinite-scrolling/app/routes/page/simple.tsx